# Cannot output an outside function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn how to output a function inside a function.

Objective; the function NameOutput() when ran should output a random number from the 'randomMath()' function.

I seem to only be able to output strings, how do I output the result of other functions if I choose to do so?

After this I will attempt to output names from an array of my choosing using the 'randomMath' function inside of my 'nameOutput' function.

```
let names = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
    // let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);


let response;

function nameOutput() {
    response = randomMath();
}


nameOutput()


let section = document.querySelector('body');
section.innerHTML = ' ';
let para1 = document.createElement('p');
para1.textContent = response;
section.appendChild(para1);

function randomMath() {
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

return value from randomMath function like this.
value needs to be returned.

```js
let names = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
    // let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);


let response;

function nameOutput() {
    response = randomMath();
}


nameOutput()


let section = document.querySelector('body');
section.innerHTML = ' ';
let para1 = document.createElement('p');
para1.textContent = response;
section.appendChild(para1);

function randomMath() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
}
```